# Rails 5 - Rails-ujs has already been loaded

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have put the tag `javascript` into my body application.

In my console I am getting this error:

> `Rails-ujs has already been loaded.`

In development mode the app works, however it doesn't work in production.

I have deployed my rails application on Heroku.

I try to move the tag `javascript` into the head, but then all function js is not working.

Any solution?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the html code that you are adding/deleting. Also show your application.js file. In development mode it's putting together the assets every time. In Heroku you are probably seeing issues due to either precompiled assets or something to do with turbolinks.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using webpack and a separate front-end, you might have two instances of your javascript tag in `application.html`.

```
= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-eval' => false
= javascript_pack_tag 'application'
```

You'll want to remove the first instance; similarly if you've used `pack_tag` to render your stylesheets, you may be experiencing CSS classes being called twice (you'll see stacked classes on an element in dev tools).

Comment: I had this issue for a long time 'data-turbolinks-eval' => false solved for me  +1

Answer (score 0):

I solved bringing my javascript into the head and simply including all my functions below:

```js
$ (document).on('turbolinks: load', function () {
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use webpack then use as like:

```
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload', 'data-turbolinks-eval': false %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'frontend_application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
</body>
```

in application.js file

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
```

in frontend_application.js file

```
//= require compress.min
//= require custom
```